# How to use fireTableDataChanged in this case? (Or what other method should I use?)

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, jtable

I am making a small program that retrieves data from a sqlite database and populates the JTable. User can also populate the database by the  proper form. Mu question is, how to update the JTable so it shows content added by user? For now, it only shows it after rerunning the whole application.

Here's the code for the table:

```
package kpkw;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;


public class MainTable {



//protected List<List<Object>> allMembers = new ArrayList<>();
//protected List<Object> member = new ArrayList<>();
protected MainTable(){

}


private  void PassFromDBtoTable(List<List<Object>> allMembers){


        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
          c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:HistoriaPrzeplywow.s3db");
          c.setAutoCommit(false);
          stmt = c.createStatement();
          rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM HistoriaPrzeplywow;" );
          while ( rs.next() ) {
              List<Object> member = new ArrayList();

             int idSQL = rs.getInt("ID");
             String id2SQL = rs.getString("ID2");
             int id3SQL = rs.getInt("ID3");
             String typSQL = rs.getString("Typ");
             String imieSQL = rs.getString("Imie");
             String nazwiskoSQL = rs.getString("Nazwisko");
             int naleznoscSQL = rs.getInt("Naleznosc");
             String tytulemSQL = rs.getString("Tytulem");
             String dataSQL = rs.getString("Data");

             member.add(idSQL);
             member.add(id2SQL);
             member.add(id3SQL);
             member.add(typSQL);
             member.add(imieSQL);
             member.add(nazwiskoSQL);
             member.add(ManageCurrency(naleznoscSQL));
             member.add(tytulemSQL);
             member.add(dataSQL);

             allMembers.add(member);

          }

        } 
          catch ( SQLException e ) {
          System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
          System.exit(0);
        }

        finally{
          if(rs!=null&& stmt!=null && c!=null){
            try{
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                c.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }       
}



private String ManageCurrency(int naleznoscSQL){
    String currency = Integer.toString(naleznoscSQL);
    currency = new StringBuilder(currency).insert(currency.length()-2, ".").toString();

    return currency;

}

private void ResizeColumnWidth(JTable table){
    final TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
    for(int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++){
        int width = 70;
        for(int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++){
            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, col);
            Component component = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
            int componentSize = component.getPreferredSize().width;
            width = Math.max(componentSize ,width);
        }
        columnModel.getColumn(col).setPreferredWidth(width);
    }
}  // method doesn't work so far




private void initUI(){




    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu plikMenu = new JMenu("Plik");


    List<List<Object>> allMembers = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object> member = new ArrayList<>();
    PassFromDBtoTable(allMembers);
    for(int i = 0; i< member.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(member.get(i));
    }
    MyTableModel mtb = new MyTableModel(allMembers);
    JTable rekordy = new JTable(mtb);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(rekordy);
    ResizeColumnWidth(rekordy);
    rekordy.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
    rekordy.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

    JMenuItem noweKPMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Nowe KP...");
    JMenuItem noweKWMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Nowe KW...");
    JMenuItem zakonczMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Zakończ");





    mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainFrame.setTitle("Historia Przepływów");
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setSize(660, 200);
    mainFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    //JButton test = new JButton("test");

    //mainFrame.add(mainPanel);

    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    mainPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //mainPanel.add(test);
    menuBar.add(plikMenu);
    plikMenu.add(noweKPMenuItem);
    plikMenu.add(noweKWMenuItem);
    plikMenu.add(zakonczMenuItem);
    mainFrame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

       noweKPMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
           //KP run = new KP();
           KP.run();
      }
   });

}



public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{



    protected List<List<Object>> allMembers = new ArrayList<>();

     public MyTableModel (List<List<Object>> allMembers) {
    this.allMembers = allMembers;
}

     protected MyTableModel(){

     }


    String[] columnNames = {"ID", "ID2", "ID3", "Typ", "Imię", "Nazwisko","Należność", "Tytułem", "Data"};


    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }  

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return allMembers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        //List<Object> row = allMembers.get(rowIndex);
        return allMembers.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
      return false;
    }




    protected  void addRecord(int ID, String ID2, int ID3, String typ, String imie, String nazwisko, int naleznosc, String tytulem, String data){
    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:HistoriaPrzeplywow.s3db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

        //pstmt = c.createStatement();
        String sqlCommand = ("INSERT INTO HistoriaPrzeplywow (ID,ID2,ID3,Typ,Imie,Nazwisko,Naleznosc,Tytulem,Data) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
        pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sqlCommand);
        pstmt.setInt(1, ID);
        pstmt.setString(2, ID2);
        pstmt.setInt(3, ID3);
        pstmt.setString(4, typ);
        pstmt.setString(5, imie);
        pstmt.setString(6, nazwisko);
        pstmt.setInt(7, naleznosc);
        pstmt.setString(8, tytulem);
        pstmt.setString(9, data);

        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        c.commit();

        List<Object> rowData = new ArrayList<>();
        rowData.add(ID);
        rowData.add(ID2);
        rowData.add(ID3);
        rowData.add(typ);
        rowData.add(imie);
        rowData.add(nazwisko);
        rowData.add(tytulem);
        rowData.add(data);

        allMembers.add(rowData);
        fireTableDataChanged();







    }
    catch(SQLException| ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if(c!=null){
            try{
                c.close();
               // pstmt.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


} 



 /*MainTable(){

    initUI();

}*/

public static void main(String args[]) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());



            MainTable guiMainTable = new MainTable();
            guiMainTable.initUI();


                        }
    });
}
}
```

And here's the form's code:

```
package kpkw;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class KP extends JFrame {
private ArrayList<JPanel> naleznosciArrayList   = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<JTextField> zaCoArrayList   = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<JTextField> zloteArrayList   = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<JTextField> grArrayList   = new ArrayList<>();
private static int liczbaWierszy = -1;



public KP() {

    initUI();
}



private void usunPole(JPanel nal){
    nal.remove(naleznosciArrayList.get(liczbaWierszy));
    naleznosciArrayList.remove(liczbaWierszy);
    liczbaWierszy--;
}

private void initUI(){

   setTitle("KP");
   setSize(500, 300);
   setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
   this.setJMenuBar(menubar);
   JMenu plik = new JMenu("Plik");
   menubar.add(plik);


   JPanel container = new JPanel();
   container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
   this.add(container);

   JPanel title = new JPanel();
   JLabel kpTytul = new JLabel("Generator KP");
   kpTytul.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 14));

   container.add(title);
   title.add(kpTytul);

   JPanel pola1 = new JPanel();
   pola1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
   container.add(pola1);

   JLabel lData = new JLabel("  Data");
   JTextField tData = new JTextField(1);
   tData.setEditable(false);
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
   Date date = new Date();
   tData.setText((dateFormat.format(date)));
   JLabel lNumer = new JLabel("  KP");

   JPanel numery = new JPanel();
   numery.setLayout(new BoxLayout(numery, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
   JTextField tNumerRef = new JTextField(1);
   tNumerRef.setEditable(false);
   Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:HistoriaPrzeplywow.s3db");
      c.setAutoCommit(false);
      stmt = c.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT Count(*) FROM HistoriaPrzeplywow;" );
      rs.next();
      int numberOfRows = rs.getInt(1)+1;
      tNumerRef.setText(Integer.toString(numberOfRows));
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if(c!=null&&rs!=null){
            try{
                c.close();
                //stmt.close();
                rs.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
   JTextField tNumerReg = new JTextField(1);
   JTextField tNumerRok = new JTextField(1);
   DateFormat rokFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
   Date dataRok = new Date();
   tNumerRok.setText((rokFormat.format(dataRok)));
   tNumerRok.setEditable(false);

   numery.add(tNumerRef);
   numery.add(tNumerReg);
   numery.add(tNumerRok);

   pola1.add(lData);
   pola1.add(tData);
   pola1.add(lNumer);
   pola1.add(numery);

   JPanel pola2 = new JPanel();
   pola2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
   container.add(pola2);

   JLabel lImie = new JLabel("  Imię");
   JTextField tImie = new JTextField(1);
   JLabel lNazwisko = new JLabel("  Nazwisko");
   JTextField tNazwisko = new JTextField(1);
   //JLabel lZaCo = new JLabel("Za co");
   //JTextField tZaCo = new JTextField(1);

   pola2.add(lImie);
   pola2.add(tImie);
   pola2.add(lNazwisko);
   pola2.add(tNazwisko);

   JPanel naleznosci = new JPanel();
    naleznosci.setLayout(new BoxLayout(naleznosci, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    JLabel lZaCo = new JLabel("Tytułem:");
    JTextField tZaCo = new JTextField(1);
    zaCoArrayList.add(tZaCo);
    JLabel gap = new JLabel("       ");
    JLabel lKasa = new JLabel("Wartość:");
    JTextField tZlote = new JTextField(1);
    zloteArrayList.add(tZlote);
    JLabel lZl = new JLabel("zł");
    JTextField tGr = new JTextField(1);
    grArrayList.add(tGr);
    JLabel lGr = new JLabel("gr");
    JLabel gap2 = new JLabel("   ");
    JLabel gap3 = new JLabel("   ");
    //JLabel lWinien = new JLabel("Winien");
    //JTextField tWinien = new JTextField(1);

    naleznosci.add(lZaCo);
    naleznosci.add(tZaCo);
    naleznosci.add(gap);
    naleznosci.add(lKasa);
    naleznosci.add(gap3);
    naleznosci.add(tZlote);
    naleznosci.add(lZl);
    naleznosci.add(tGr);
    naleznosci.add(lGr);

    container.add(naleznosci);


   JPanel separator = new JPanel();
   container.add(separator);
   separator.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));

   JButton generuj = new JButton("Generuj");
   container.add(generuj);
   generuj.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

   generuj.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

           if(tImie.getText().equals("") || tNazwisko.getText().equals("") || tNumerReg.getText().equals("") || tZaCo.getText().equals("") || tZlote.getText().equals("") || tGr.getText().equals("")){
               //System.out.println("Nie wypełniono wszystkich pól");
               ErrorWindow.setMessage("<html><center>Nie wypełniono wszystkich pól</center></html>");
               ErrorWindow.main();
           }
           else {

               try{
                   int ID = Integer.parseInt(tNumerRef.getText());
                   int ID3 = Integer.parseInt(tNumerRok.getText());
                   String typ = "KP";
                   String naleznosc = tZlote.getText() + tGr.getText();
                   int naleznoscInt = Integer.parseInt(naleznosc);
                   MainTable mt = new MainTable();
                   mt.new MyTableModel().addRecord(ID, tNumerReg.getText(), ID3, typ, tImie.getText(), tNazwisko.getText(), naleznoscInt, tZaCo.getText(), tData.getText());


               }
               catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }




           }
      }
   });










}

public static void run() {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            KP gui = new KP();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What a whole lot of code! Too much to be useful. Can you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

```
MainTable mt = new MainTable();
mt.new MyTableModel().addRecord(...);
```

Don't create a new JTable. You need to access the existing TableModel of the JTable that is displayed in the frame. Then you invoke the addRecord(...) method on that table model.

Also in your custom TableModel you are using:

```
fireTableDataChanged();
```

That is the wrong method since you did not change all the data. All you did was add a single row of data, so you should be using:

```
fireTableRowsInserted(...);
```